# what is SET_NETDEV_DEV function is Does it make "pci_dev" a parent of "net_device". What does it do. RealTek

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, ethernet, pci

In RealTek Device driver for Ethernet driver it does something like

```
    SET_NETDEV_DEV(net_dev_obj, &pci_dev_obj->dev);
```

What the above line means why pci_dev has to be parent of net_device. Can net_device be a parent of pci_dev

Before above line driver does something like

```
     dev = devm_alloc_etherdev(&pci_dev_obj->dev, sizeof (*my_struct_obj));
```

`my_struct_obj` is my structure and in r8169 driver from realTek it defined as

```
    struct my_struct_obj
    {
        void __iomem *mmio_addr;    /* memory map physical address */
        struct pci_dev *pci_dev;
        struct net_device *dev;
        struct phy_device *phydev;
        struct napi_struct napi;
        enum mac_version mac_version;
        u32 cur_rx; /* Index into the Rx descriptor buffer of next Rx pkt. */
        u32 cur_tx; /* Index into the Tx descriptor buffer of next Rx pkt. */
        u32 dirty_tx;
        struct rtl8169_stats rx_stats;
        struct rtl8169_stats tx_stats;
        struct TxDesc *TxDescArray; /* 256-aligned Tx descriptor ring */
        struct RxDesc *RxDescArray; /* 256-aligned Rx descriptor ring */
        dma_addr_t TxPhyAddr;
        dma_addr_t RxPhyAddr;
        struct page *Rx_databuff[NUM_RX_DESC];  /* Rx data buffers */
        struct ring_info tx_skb[NUM_TX_DESC];   /* Tx data buffers */
        u16 cp_cmd;
        u32 irq_mask;
        struct clk *clk;

        struct {
            DECLARE_BITMAP(flags, RTL_FLAG_MAX);
            struct work_struct work;
        } wk;

        unsigned supports_gmii:1;
        unsigned aspm_manageable:1;
        dma_addr_t counters_phys_addr;
        struct rtl8169_counters *counters;
        struct rtl8169_tc_offsets tc_offset;
        u32 saved_wolopts;
        int eee_adv;

        const char *fw_name;
        struct rtl_fw *rtl_fw;

        u32 ocp_base;
    };
```

What this mean `dev = devm_alloc_etherdev(&pci_dev_obj->dev, sizeof (*my_struct_obj));`

In the book Linux Device Drivers it talk about `alloc_netdev(int sizeof_my_struct_object,name,void (*setup(struct net_device *)))`
Since `alloc_netdev` sounds like for allocation of network driver memory space in RAM and `devm_alloc_etherdev` is also about this but my question is why `devm_alloc_etherdev(dev, sizeof(my_struct_object))` does requires net_device and `sizeof` my_object as arguments, shouldn't it require `my_struct_object` as its first argument.

I assume `devm_alloc_etherdev` allocate the net_device's private data  (which is its first argument:net_device) to the size of my_struct_object. If this is true then please confirm.

Any connection helps how `my_struct_object`, pci_dev, and net_device are connected to one and other. All I know

In short just tell me what is

```
    dev = devm_alloc_etherdev(&pdev->dev, sizeof (*tp));
```

and

```
   SET_NETDEV_DEV(dev, &pdev->dev);
```

and why they are important lines

Or

is SET_NETDEV_DEV connects pci_dev to net_device

and

devm_alloc_etherdev connects pci_dev to my_struct_object how since it only takes the size of argument

and these are the lines afterwards

```
   my_struct_object = netdev_priv(dev);
   my_struct_object->dev = dev;
   my_struct_object->pci_dev = pdev;
```

These above three lines shouldn't only there without the first two lines that I mentioned in the question. Following is the full code

```
     net_device_obj = devm_alloc_etherdev(&pci_dev_obj->dev, sizeof (*my_struct_obj));
     SET_NETDEV_DEV(net_dev_obj, &pci_dev_obj->dev);
    my_struct_object = netdev_priv(dev);
    my_struct_object->dev = dev;
    my_struct_object->pci_dev = pdev;
```

Comment: Virtual devices (that are present only in the Linux device model) are children of real devices. This is by design. Read a good book about Linux internals.